# Как распарсить json из vk api на Python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, telegram-bot

Делаю бота для новостного канала в Telegram, столкнулся с такой проблемой: получаю json от vk api, а распарсить его не получается. Подскажите, как это сделать? 
json вида:

```js
response: [{
id: 210700286,
first_name: 'Lindsey',
last_name: 'Stirling',
city: {
id: 5331,
title: 'Los Angeles'
},
photo_50: 'https://pp.vk.me/...f6e/4-funfNRMwg.jpg',
verified: 1
}]
```

Понимаю, что не получается его распарсить из за response, но как его убрать?

Comment: Пример в вопросе не [json](http://json.org). Если бы это был бы  json, то не имело бы значения откуда вы его взяли (можно было бы убрать из вопроса упоминание vk, telegram). Попробуйте минимальный пример кода создать—сделайте запрос любым способом к vk api и покажите что вы получаете в ответ (`print(repr(response))`). Опишите какую информацию вы хотите извлечь и в чём конкретно у вас проблема с кодом. Если возможно сделать запрос к vk вне telegram, то уберите упоминание telegram из вопроса (решайте одну проблему за раз).

Answer (score -1):

```
import json

result=json.loads(text)
```